# Is OSCompareAndSwap immune to ABA problem like CMPXCHG8B?

Tags: macos, assembly, kernel, atomic, compare-and-swap

Is OSCompareAndSwap is immune to ABA problem like CMPXCHG8B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on the implementation. OSCompareAndSwap* is only an interface which guarantee an atomic CAS operator (if the CPU supports it).

For [x86](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1228.9.59/libkern/i386/OSAtomic.s) this function for 64-bit is implemented as

```
_OSCompareAndSwap64:
    pushl       %edi
    pushl       %ebx

    movl         4+8(%esp), %eax    #; low 32-bits of oldValue
    movl         8+8(%esp), %edx    #; high 32-bits of oldValue
    movl        12+8(%esp), %ebx    #; low 32-bits of newValue
    movl        16+8(%esp), %ecx    #; high 32-bits of newValue
    movl        20+8(%esp), %edi    #; ptr
    lock
    cmpxchg8b   0(%edi)     #; CAS (eax:edx, ebx:ecx implicit)
    sete        %al         #; did CAS succeed? (TZ=1)
    movzbl      %al, %eax       #; clear out the high bytes

    popl        %ebx
    popl        %edi
    ret
```

so the answer for you probably is "yes".

Comment: +1 thanks Kenny. So _OSCompareAndSwap64 contains cmpxchg8b, I guess it should be immune to ABA problem then.

Comment: @Viet: CAS *is* vulnerable to ABA problems, unlike LL/SC.  If the target 64-bit value changed to B and is now back to A, `cmpxchg8b` will succeed even though stuff has happened since you initially read A.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap#ABA_problem.  If your 64-bit value is a 32-bit pointer and a 32-bit counter, then ABA can't happen.  That's why you're using a DWCAS (double-word CAS) in the first place.  Not because DWCAS itself is immune to ABA, but because it gives you room to add uniquifying data to what you're using CAS on.